# Why is mat-accordion is not displaying in StackBlitz?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on a quiz app and the actual mat-accordion with the questions and answers summary doesn't seem to to display in StackBlitz which is in my ResultsComponent when you click the "View detailed summary" link. Only the expand/collapse buttons show. Please see my StackBlitz here: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app**

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I am using mat-accordion with mat-expansion-panel, but it doesn't seem to display. I've imported MatExpansionModule in my app.module.ts. It works fine in my IDE.

Comment: I looked at your stackblitz and don't see any issue. You need to explicitly state what the actual problem is. Also, don't just throw a stackblitz. Make a minimal reproducible example. Otherwise, you'll just continue to get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

you has in result

```
*ngFor="let panel of accordionList; let question of quizData.questions; index as i"
```

You can not use this kinf of *ngFor (futhermore, accordionList is nothing)

must be (I suppose)

```
*ngFor="let question of quizData.questions; index as i"
```

***Updated** There're another bug moew bellow, you has

```
 *ngFor="let finalAnswer of finalAnswers;
         let correctAnswer of correctAnswers"
```

You can not do this king of things if you want to has two *ngFor use a `<ng-container>`

```
<div *ngFor="let finalAnswer of finalAnswers">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let correctAndser of correctAnswers>
        ...
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Or use an index if the two arrays has the same length

```
<div *ngFor="let finalAnswer of finalAnswers;let i=index">
   {{correctAnswers[i]}}
</div>
```

Comment: I've removed the "let panel of accordionList" and the accordion now displays but the databinding inside the accordion items (inside quiz-summary-field divs) doesn't seem to show.

Comment: I think the problem are yours *ngFor, I beleive that you can not do this kind of things, I updated the answer

Comment: I went with the second approach as the two arrays should be the same length, but still not getting anything displayed in the accordion.